# Rails 3 URL Routing on Apache

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm aware that in the past, Rails used .htaccess and/or httpd.conf as a 'gateway' on Apache for routing urls.

What exactly does Rails 3 use to route urls?

Comment: Rails routing system parses server requests and uses the route mappings defined in routes.rb to 'route' your requests to the appropriate controller and action. It doesn't use .htaccess or anything the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the use of apache or nginx is not necessary for production.

You can run your rails application with a ruby server like unicorn, thin or another one. All these servers are based on Rack. Rack uses routes that are described in file config.ru. It is the first step of routing. The next step is rails routing (as Strelok said routes.rb).

But the best way is to use nginx or apache (but in this case, the better is nginx) like first step. It will give all static content from /public folder and all other requests it will send to the ruby server.

So in this case the first step is described in nginx config, the second in config.ru, and the last one in routes.rb

Comment: So if you have Apache or Nginx, but don't use ruby servers, does rails still make use of the configuration files to send requests to the routes files?

Comment: Patrick, if you don't use ruby server and use fcgi or passenger, you just skip step with config.ru routing. In this case the first step is .htaccess or nginx config and the second step is routes.rb.